# Артефакты прорисовки теней в рамке с уголком

Tags: html, css

Надо мне сверстать рамку с уголком подобного вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подобных вопросов и на `ruSO`, и в сети находится достаточно, как сделать на чистом css и без картинок. Сделал по гайдлайнам что-то типа:

```css
    .sticky {
        width: 20rem;
    }

    .sticky div {
        position:relative;
        background-color: #FFFFCC;
        padding: 1rem 2rem;
        box-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), -1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    }
    
    .sticky div:before {
        content:"";
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        right:0;
        border-width:0 16px 16px 0;
        border-style:solid;
        border-color:#FFFF99 #fff;
        box-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1), -1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.01);
    }
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="sticky">
            <div>
                <h3>Some text here</h3>
                <p>Phone: 322 223</p>
                <p>Email: <a href="mailto:test@example.tld">test@example.tld</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Я не понял, как сделать диагональную линию, но в принципе, накидав побольше теней получил вполне устраивающий результат в Firefox:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но когда я открываю это всё в Chrome я вижу какую-то уродливую тень, заметную невооружённым глазом (потом пересматривая в FF под лупой вижу, что и там она есть, но не так сильно бросается в глаза)

Выключена внешняя тень, оставлена тень от уголка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выключена тень от уголка, оставлена внешняя тень:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Без теней листочек получается какой-то бедный с изобразительной точки зрения, ненастоящий, поэтому у меня возникает следующий вопрос: как кроссбраузерно сделать тень только слева и снизу и чтобы сверху и справа не было не было артефактов?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Box-shadow: blur & spread

Используя свойство *box-shadow*, чаще всего указывают всего три параметра: смещение по *X*, смещение по *Y* и размер размытия (*blur*). При этом незаслуженно забывая ещё об одном параметре — *spread*.
В разных мануалах, его называют по-разному — распространение или сжатие — скорее всего, это потому, что параметр может принимать, как положительные значения, так и отрицательные, в зависимости от задач. А также потому, что например, в Chrome этот параметр нельзя выставить меньше нуля нативным средством в инспекторе стилей (хотя, прописав значение вручную, всё прекрасно отображается и работает, если не двигать ползунок):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так что же делает этот параметр? Интерактивный пример, расставляет всё по местам:

```css
.controls{display:flex;justify-content:space-around;text-align:center}.controls input{display:block}:root{--cx:0;--cy:0;--sb:50px;--ss:0}.example{margin:15px auto;width:350px;height:70px;line-height:70px;text-align:center;box-sizing:border-box;border:4px solid #fa0;background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0);box-shadow:var(--cx) var(--cy) var(--sb) var(--ss) rgba(0,0,0,0.5)}
```

```html
<div class="controls" oninput="document.querySelector('.example').innerText=getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.example')).boxShadow;"> <div>offset_X (-n...n)<input type="range" min="-100" max="100" oninput="document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--cx', this.value + 'px');">смещение по X</div><div>offset_Y (-n...n)<input type="range" min="-100" max="100" oninput="document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--cy', this.value + 'px');">смещение по Y</div><div>blur (0...n)<input type="range" min="0" max="100" oninput="document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--sb', this.value + 'px');">размытие</div><div>spread (-n...n)<input type="range" min="-100" max="100" oninput="document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--ss', this.value + 'px');">распространение</div></div><div class="example">rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 50px 0px</div>
```

Подведём итоги наблюдений:

- **Смещения** — могут быть, как положительными, так и отрицательными;
- **Размытие** — это не размер тени, хотя и влияет на её размер визуально. Размытие как бы смазывает границу тени. Может принимать только положительное значение;
- **Распространение** — это размер тени, относительно блока, который её отбрасывает. Может принимать, как положительные, так и отрицательные значения. Отрицательное значение не может быть меньше половины меньшего из размеров блока. Например, если *height* блока 70px, то при значении *spread* меньше -34px тень просто схлопнется (70 / 2 - 35 = 0). При этом, исчезнет и её размытие, каким бы большим оно ни было, т.к. размывать нечего.

---

После небольшого отступления в теорию, переходим к ответу на вопрос:

```css
body {
  background-color: #d4ebf7;
}
.sticky,
.sticky_right {
  /* Здесь добавил и изменил стили только для сниппета */
  width: 18rem;
  float: left;
  margin: 3px;
}

/**********************
* Исправленный стикер *
**********************/
.sticky div {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #FFFFCC;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
}
.sticky div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  border-width: 0 16px 16px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #FFFF99 #fff;
  box-shadow: -1px 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.sticky div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  box-shadow: -2px 3px 3px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

/********************
* Правильный стикер *
********************/
.sticky_right div {
  position: relative;
  /* Фон изменён со сплошного на градиент */
  background-image: linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 10px, #FFFFCC 10px);
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
}
.sticky_right div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  border-width: 0 16px 16px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  /* Цвет изменён с белого на прозрачный */
  border-color: #FFFF99 transparent;
  box-shadow: -1px 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.sticky_right div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  box-shadow: -2px 3px 3px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
    <div class="sticky">
      <div>
        <h3>Some text here</h3>
        <p>Phone: 322 223</p>
        <p>Email: <a href="mailto:test@example.tld">test@example.tld</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sticky_right">
      <div>
        <h3>Some text here</h3>
        <p>Phone: 322 223</p>
        <p>Email: <a href="mailto:test@example.tld">test@example.tld</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Алгоритм прост, изменения минимальны:

1. **`:before`** — в свойстве `box-shadow` с помощью параметра *spread* уменьшаем размер тени, но при этом сдвигаем тень ещё больше, в том же направлении, куда она была сдвинута ранее. Добавляем положительный `z-index`, на всякий случай.
2. **`:after`** — добавляем. Выравниваем по левому и нижнему краю. Растягиваем по размерам родителя. Позиционируем с помощью отрицательного `z-index` за блоком. С  `box-shadow` проводим те же манипуляции, что и с предыдущим блоком — уменьшаем тень четвёртым параметром и сдвигаем влево вниз.

Таким образом, за счёт *смещений*, тень осталась на своём месте, но из-за отрицательного *распространения*, стала меньше и спряталась под основной блок на противоположных от направления *смещений* краях.

---

PS Т.к. была замечена, на мой взгляд, ещё одна недоработка — непрозрачность в месте отгиба — добавил рядом ещё вариант для сравнения. Кроссбраузерность напрямую зависит от поддержки `linear-gradient`.

Comment: Да, это работает. А в чём фокус - можете объяснить? Типа, :after что-то скрывает из артефактов так как у него z-index выше находится?

Comment: @AK весь фокус в четвёртом параметре _spread_ у `box-shadow`. Извините, убегаю с работы уже)) Думаю, что разберётесь - http://htmlbook.ru/css/box-shadow

Comment: @UModeL не извеняю обясни люди ждут :)

Comment: @Избытоксусликов ок, дополню ответ, распишу подробнее, но нужно время. Ждёмс :-)

Comment: @UModeL ждем :)

Comment: @Избытоксусликов попытался изложить, как можно понятнее и проще.

Comment: @UModeL благодарю ..я свой плюсь еще вчера дал к ответу когда первый свой коммент поставил на данный пост.

Comment: @Избытоксусликов спасибо. Я здесь не из-за плюсиков ;-)

Comment: @UModeL отличный ответ!

Comment: @Alexandr_TT мне есть с кого пример брать ;-)