# Не могу объеденить два блока в СSS

Tags: css3

Ребята помогите решить задачу.

```css
.menu * {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.menu {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 18px;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu>li {
  margin: 15px;
  float: left;
}

.menu>li:hover>a {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  border-bottom: none;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
}

.menu>li:hover>.under-menu {
  display: block;
}

.under-menu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px;
  display: none;
  width: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px;
  position: absolute;
}

.under-menu>li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.under-menu>li a:hover {
  color: white;
}

.under-menu>li:hover {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="">Файл</a>
    <ul class="under-menu">
      <li><a href="">Новий</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Відчинити</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Зберегти</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Заченити</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Правка</a>
    <ul class="under-menu">
      <li><a href="">Вирізати</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Копіювати</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Вставити</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Зачинити</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Есть **2** блока, они они обведены  `box-shadow`. В месте где эти блоки пересекаются ***под верхней надписью `Файл` или `Правка`***,  есть размытая линия, а мне надо что-бы они смотрелись слитно, без этой линии.
И если не сложно гляньте на код `CSS` **начинающего** и подскажите, что можно или нужно поправить, что бы код был более логичен и соответствовал лучшей практике.
Заранее спасибо)))

[Js-Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ZubiZub/7bufapkn/1/)

Comment: Не понятно чего вы хотите

Comment: Когда на новодишь курсор на ссылку, всплывает под меню. Они окружены тенью ( box-shadow:). Мне надо убрать размытую линию в месте их соединения, что бы они смотрелись слитно.

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите что Вам нужно добавить:
Для того что бы тень .under-menu не перекрывала кнопку нужно задать для .under-menu и .menu>li>a свойство z-index, таким образом, что .under-menu будет находиться под кнопкой, не забывайте, для того что бы z-index работал обязательно надо указывать position. Для того что бы тень кнопки снизу не было видно и они "слились" нужно указать для .menu>li>a свойство overflow-y: hidden, это обрежет выступающую тень по вертикали. Вот что нужно добавить к Вашему коду:

```
.menu>li>a{
  display: block;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.menu>li {
    overflow-y: hidden;
} 
.under-menu {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

В принципе Ваш код достаточно правилен, Вы логично используете html теги, советую еще почитать о семантике html5, и правильно делаете, что не перегружаете код классами, а пользуетеcь в качестве селекторов тегами, но этим также не стоит злоупотреблять.
Надеюсь ответ Вам поможет.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Крайне рекомендую почитать - [Box-shadow: blur & spread](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/909132/265406)

```css
.menu * { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }

.menu { color: blue; font-size: 18px; list-style: none; }

.menu>li { position: relative; margin: 15px; float: left; }

.menu>li>a { padding: 5px 5px 10px; }

.menu>li:hover>a {
  box-shadow: -3px -2px 5px -3px blue, 3px -2px 5px -3px blue;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #fff;
}

.menu>li:hover>.under-menu { display: block; }

.under-menu {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 27px;
  display: none;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  list-style: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px;
}

.under-menu>li a { text-decoration: none; }

.under-menu>li a:hover { color: white; }

.under-menu>li:hover { background: blue; }
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="">Файл</a>
    <ul class="under-menu">
      <li><a href="">Новий</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Відчинити</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Зберегти</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Заченити</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Правка</a>
    <ul class="under-menu">
      <li><a href="">Вирізати</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Копіювати</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Вставити</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Зачинити</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Интересная заметка, спасибо.

Comment: @DimaZubarev старался, как мог)) Надеюсь, что поможет в будущем.