# Box-shadow как работает размытие?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, box-shadow

Зачем указывать в box-shadow размытие 10px при горизонтальном и вертикальном смещении, установленными по нулям?

```css
p {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}


/*CSS #1*/

p.four1 {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 #777777;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 #777777;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #777777;
}


/*CSS #2*/

p.four2 {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 #777777;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 #777777;
  box-shadow: 0 0 560px #777777;
}
```

```html
<p class="four1"><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></p>
<p class="four2"><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></p>
```

Ничего не изменяется если менять значение размытия. Никакой разницы при запуске кода CSS #1 и CSS #2 нету. Зачем вообще указывать размытие при горизонтальном и вертикальном смещении, установленными по нулям?

Comment: Я обновил вопрос

Comment: Перенес твой код в сниппет - вроде разница очевидна в отображени?

Comment: Разница в примере, который адаптировал Grundy, очень даже хорошо видна, непонятно о чём вопрос

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский, я говорю нету разницы при 0 0 10px #77777

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский т.е. нету разницы при установленных в ноль значениях горизонтального и вертикального смещений

Comment: @JustLearn покажите скриншот с двумя блоками с разными box-shadow, на котором мы тоже могли бы не увидеть разницы. Сейчас мы разницу отчётливо видим и ничего не понимаем

Comment: Спасибо за ответы! Всё почему-то стало работать) Ничего не менял просто снова запустил)) Прикол)

Comment: @JustLearn рекомендую к прочтению - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/909132/265406

Comment: @UModel спасибо, прочту)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут ты неправ.

Как можно видеть, размытие при нулевых смещениях есть, и чем больше - тем заметнее.

```css
p {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 50px;
  background: grey;
}

.number-1 {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
}
```

```html
<p class="number-1"></p>
<p class="number-2"></p>
```

И, кстати, хочу заметить вот что: ты поставил префиксы для браузеров chrome, safari и mozilla - у них ты не указал размытия, а уже потом (в свойстве без префикса) - указал значение свойства с размытием. Я думаю так: ты проверял вёрстку в одном из этих браузеров, и поэтому у тебя не отобразились изменения при любых радиусах размытия. Так что исправить это можно либо удалением вендорных префиксов, либо в написании в каждом свойстве с префиксом одного и того же значения радиуса размытия.