# Как отрезать край у блока оставив ему тень и загнутый уголок?

Tags: css

Коллеги, добрый день.
Прошу вас подскажите наиболее удобоваримый вариант для отрезания края у блока.
САБЖ: есть контейнер, которому надо "загнуть уголок" и пи этом не потерять тень контейнера. При чем сама тень, должна огибать сгиб.

Подробно на скриншоте
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Clip-path - не пашет, обрезается общая тень блока.
Классическое решение с треугольным элементом как раз наоборот, не отрезает тень у этого угла.
Решение с градиентом - тоже не подходит, по этой же причине.

Прошу, подскажите, как можно было бы отрезать угол и тень оставить только там, где она нужна.

Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Comment: По-моему тут нету простых решений на css. Можно какой-нибудь мега-костыль смастерить, с которым потом будет страшно самому ходить )

Comment: @Polina: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/909106/